# Conditional dependence between two ordinal variables

Tags: independence, ordinal-data, conditional

I really hope that this question was not answered in any way before, but I couldn't find an appropriate solution to my problem - most probably due to my lack of statistical knowledge.

I am trying to compute the significance that two ordinal variables A and B are conditionally dependent from each other. Each variable contains only two groups building together a 2x2 contingency table (A and not A, B and not B). I want to make sure that the *p*-value from A and B can be different from B and A, i.e. it is important that the order is taken into account.

A paper that I would like to build upon uses a one-tailed Fisher's Exact Test to test A and B for conditional dependence. However, the authors treat the variables as categorical and ignore the fact that A and B as well as B and A are two distinct cases. I think that a Chi-squared test does not work properly since the sample sizes can be very small.

Hence my question: Which statistical test might be appropriate to test whether A and B are conditionally dependent?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain what hypotheses these two p-values might be testing?  Exactly what is being specified by "from A and B" that is any different than "from B and A"?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! Sure, I will do my best: A and B are in fact two physical entities that can occur together in nature. To be more specific, A and B are distinct regions (e.g. A = "CDE", B = "FGH") in a sequence of characters. The question is, whether the co-occurrence of A and B is significant, i.e. whether A and B are conditionally dependent. So does A normally occur with B and vice-versa. However, it was shown that the frequency of A occurring with B is rather different to the frequency of B occurring with A. Therefore, this "directionality" has somehow taken into account.

Comment: Do you mean something like $A$ after $B$ being different than $B$ after $A$?

Comment: Yes, exactly! The order of A and B is different to B and A. And there will be different frequencies of A-B and B-A , respectively. However, the number of sequences where A is absent but B present is the same for both orders, of course. The same goes for sequences where A is present but B absent and sequences where both A and B are absent. I thought about the possibility of using one-sided Fisher's exact test for both orders A-B and B-A separately, but I am unsure if there exists a dependency between these two orders.