# Test for conditional dependence

Tags: hypothesis-testing, conditional-probability, independence, conditioning

I am trying to find out whether two variables are conditionally dependent on each other. I would like to have a test for B implies A (B->A) or not and one for A implies B (A->B) or not. It is important that these two tests can give different p-values.

I have a contingency table with A, not A on the columns and B not B on the rows. If B->A, in the first row I would expect to never (or very rarely see) data with B and not A. On the second row I would expect almost all data that doesn't have A to not have B, but we can have A without B:

|  | A | not A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 98 | 2 |
| not B | 40 | 98 |

I understand that there are tests for statistical independence but what I want is slightly different as independence would also be dismissed when A and B are mutually exclusive while I want to test if they are conditional.

For a bit of context; I want to get a temporal ordering of mutational events: "A happened in population B", "B happened in population A" or "A and B happened in the root population".

I have found a similar question here: [Conditional dependence between two ordinal variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399398/conditional-dependence-between-two-ordinal-variables) but unfortunately without answer yet.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If I understand the linked question correctly, that question has actually 5 categories; [notA, notB], [notA, B], [A, notB] [A, B, A after B], [A,B, B after A]. Is it the same for your data?

Comment: Maybe the linked question is a bit confusing, in the comments they clarify that they want to test for "A then B" and "B then A" instead of "A and B" (which would be symmetrical). For my data I want to test for "A then B", "B then A" and "A and B at the same time"

Comment: I think I understand what hypothesis you and the other question want to test, but the data; in the other question there are 5 different numbers, but in yours there are 4 numbers, right?

Comment: Yes in my data there are 4 numbers in the table. Maybe I understood the other question incorrectly but they also have a 2*2 contingency table, which would give then 4 numbers?